# Single Ajax Function That Able To Call Different PHP page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have button below on my index.html:

```html
<button value="about_us.php" onClick="fNt(value)">About Us</button>
<button value="faq.php" onClick="fNt(value)">FAQ</button>
<button value="contact_us.php" onClick="fNt(value)">Contact Us</button>
```

which I want to use AJAX to get info from php page as of value. I know I can create 3 AJAX function to target 3 php page, but if I have more buttons later it will consume much space.

So, I wonder is it possible to write something like this?

```
<script>
function fNt(value) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","variable of clicked value",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200{
document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}}}
</script>
```

I know the script above won't work, it is just to show you what I try to achieve, any idea how to do it? Pls help.

Comment: See my answer. You just missed `)` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Use your browser console to check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, It will help you...

```js
function fNt(url) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="fNt('about_us.php')">About Us</button>
<button onClick="fNt('faq.php')">FAQ</button>
<button onClick="fNt('contact_us.php')">ContactUs</button>
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Regardless, you will have to create a separate callback for each button (unless you want the action of clicking each button to do the exact same thing). Why not put the uniform ajax code in a function and pass to that function a url and a separate callback function. If you want to check the request object status, just pass it directly to the callback:

```
function doGet(route, callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = "GET",
        url = route; //If you need to massage the route or anything

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = callback(xhr);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Then to call it:

```
var route = "routedesired.com";
var callback = function(xhrObj){
   if (xhrObj.readyState == 4 && xhrObj.status == 200{
       console.log("HELLO WORLD")
   }
}
```

**Another Approach**

I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do, but if you want to do something different for each link, you can just add the route to the callback function as well inside the `doGet` function I created:

```
function doGet(route){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        method = "GET",
        url = route; //if you need to massage the route or anything

    var callback = function(routeParam){
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200{
           switch(routeParam){
              case "faq.php":{
                 //do some action if route is "faq.php"
              }
              break;
              //continue with the same logic for other URL's
           }
        }
    }

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = callback(route);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Then to call it:

```
<button onClick="doGet('about_us.php')">About Us</button>
<button onClick="doGet('faq.php')">FAQ</button>
<button onClick="doGet('contact_us.php')">Contact Us</button>
```

**Ultimately, there are different ways to structure it to automate the process and reduce the amount of code that you need. A part of how you approach it is dependent on what you plan on doing after the request succeeds.**